# Unity - Virtual Joystick - Camera rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, joystick

I have a virtual movement joystick  that I'm using to control the movement of a player object which works fine, the code for this is below.

The problem I have is when I rotate the camera within game mode (or device) the direction is not adjusted according to the cameras rotation, exactly like is shown in [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/147190/how-to-change-the-virtual-joystick-input-direction-depending-on-camera-rotation) post here that I looked through to try and understand the problem.

I realise I need to rotate my movement around the forward direction the camera is facing which I tried to do with the bottom snippet of code however this yields really strange behavior when the player object moves incredibly fast and eventually unity becomes unresponsive, so something is being incorrectly multiplied I guess.

Could anybody point out where I'm going wrong please? ta !
Edit - Modified to potential answer

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using EasyJoystick; 


public class NewJoystick : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float speed;
    [SerializeField] private Joystick1 joystick; 
    [SerializeField] Camera MainCam;
    private Rigidbody RB;
    private Transform cameraTransform; 
     // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
         cameraTransform = MainCam.transform; 
        
        
    }
    void Awake()
    {
         RB = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
        float xMovement = joystick.Horizontal();
        float zMovement = joystick.Vertical();  
        Vector3 inputDirection = new Vector3(xMovement, 0, zMovement);
        //Get the camera horizontal rotation
        Vector3 faceDirection = new Vector3(cameraTransform.forward.x, 0, cameraTransform.forward.z);
        //Get the angle between world forward and camera
        float cameraAngle = Vector3.SignedAngle(Vector3.forward, faceDirection, Vector3.up);
        //Finally rotate the input direction horizontally by the cameraAngle
        Vector3 moveDirection = Quaternion.Euler(0, cameraAngle, 0) * inputDirection;
        RB.velocity  = moveDirection * speed;

        
    }
}
```

I tried this in the update loop -

```
  var Direction = transform.position += new Vector3(xMovement, 0f,zMovement);  //* speed * Time.deltaTime; 
        Vector3 newDir = MainCam.transform.TransformDirection(Direction); 
        transform.position += new Vector3(newDir.x, 0f,newDir.z) * speed * Time.deltaTime;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, here is a simple idea for how to solve it. At least this is how I did it, and it seems to work ever since.

First, you need to get the joystick input, like you did. Both axis input value should be between -1 and 1. This actually determines the direction itself, since the horizontal axis gives you the X coordinate of a vector and the vertical gives you the Y coordinate of that vector. You can visualize it easily:

> [image]

Mind, that I just put up some random values there, but you get the idea.

> Now, your problem is, that this angle you get from your raw input is
> static in direction, meaning that it doesn't rely on the camera's face
> direction. You can solve this problem by "locking it to the camera",
> or in other words, rotate the input direction based on the camera
> rotation. Here's a quick example:

```
//Get the input direction
float inputX = joystick.Horizontal();
float inputY = joystick.Vertical();
Vector3 inputDirection = new Vector3(inputX, 0, inputY);

//Get the camera horizontal rotation
Vector3 faceDirection = new Vector3(cameraTransform.forward.x, 0, cameraTransform.forward.z);

//Get the angle between world forward and camera
float cameraAngle = Vector3.SignedAngle(Vector3.forward, faceDirection, Vector3.up);

//Finally rotate the input direction horizontally by the cameraAngle
Vector3 moveDirection = Quaternion.Euler(0, cameraAngle, 0) * inputDirection;
```

> **IMPORTANT:** The code above should be called in the Update cycle, since that is where you get the input information.

After this, you can work with `moveDirection` to move your player. (I suggest using physics for moving, instead of modifying its position)

Simple moving example:

```
public RigidBody rigidbody;
public Vector3 moveDirection;
public float moveSpeed = 5f;

void FixedUpdate()
{
   rigidbody.velocity = moveDirection * moveSpeed;
}
```

Comment: Edit - had RB constraints on, all working, thankyou very much !